# Logic Error - Create a Car Class with Acceleration and Braking

Tags: java, class

When running the code, there appears to be a logic error where the current speed starts at 0, and is supposed to increase over 5 increments. However, the problem is that it remains at 0 throughout the 5 increments. But, the braking part works as intended. Can anyone please help me in finding out what I am doing wrong here? I  cannot seem to locate my error on my own, or by googling other resources. Please forgive my garbage code in advance, this is my first project.

```
public class Car {
private static int Speed = 0;
private String Make = "Ford";
private int yearModel = 2013;
    
public Car (int i, String n, int Model)
{   
    Make = n;
    yearModel = Model; 
}

public static int getSpeed ()
{
    return Speed;
}   

public String getMake ()
{
    return Make;
}

public int getyearModel ()
{
    return yearModel;
}

    
public void accelerate ()
{
    if (Speed !=0)
        Speed = Speed +5;
}

public void brake ()
{
    if (Speed !=90)
        Speed = Speed -5;
}

public void setSpeed(int speed) {
    speed = speed;
}

public void accelerateSpeed() {
}
```

}

And then my runner

```
public class CarRun {
public static void main (String [] str)
{
    Car car1 = new Car(0, "Ford", 2013);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)

    {
        car1.accelerateSpeed();
        System.out.println("Current speed is: " + Car.getSpeed());
    }
    
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)

    {
        car1.brake();
        System.out.println("Current speed is: " + Car.getSpeed());
    }       
    
}
```

}

Comment: can I get the system.out.println message since you said the brake part is working fine and you have nothing inside accelerateSpeed() method.

Answer (score 0):

Your car starts at speed 0, and the accelerate function has a "  if (Speed !=0)" clause before incrementing it. Thus the speed is stuck at 0 and never gets incremenred. I would suggest changing that if statement to your intended behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely you'll see that you are initializing the speed variable as 0 as follows:

```
private static int Speed = 0;
```

And your accelerate() method won't do anything with a 0 speed car, because of the if clause:

```
public void accelerate ()
{
    if (Speed !=0)
        Speed = Speed +5;
}
```

Another problem is that you're not calling the accelerate method in your program Main as you can see in the line:

```
car1.accelerateSpeed();
```

So, for your code to work properly remove the if clause from your accelerate method and change the method call from car1.accelerateSpeed(); to:

```
car1.accelerate();
```